# Wildfly - “Conector 'netty' não encontrado no arquivo de configuração principal”

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, jms

Eu adicionei uma fábrica de conexões no arquivo `standalone-full` do `Wildfly`.:

```xml
<jms-connection-factories>
    <connection-factory name="K19Factory">
        <connectors>
            <connector-ref connector-name="netty"/>
        </connectors>
        <entries>
            <entry name="K19Factory"/>
            <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/K19Factory"/>
        </entries>
    </connection-factory>
</jms-connection-factories>
```

E eu tenho o seguinte código para utilizá-lo:

```
Properties props = new Properties();

props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial","org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");

props.setProperty("java.naming.provider.url", "http-remoting://127.0.0.1:8080/"); 

/*props.setProperty("java.naming.provider.url","remote://localhost:8080");*/

props.setProperty("java.naming.security.principal","k19");

props.setProperty("java.naming.security.credentials","1234");

InitialContext ic = new InitialContext(props);

// factory of JMS connections
ConnectionFactory factory = (ConnectionFactory)ic.lookup("jms/K19Factory");
```

Mas eu estou tendo problemas. O `Widfly` está dizendo que não consegue encontrar o connector `Netty`, e logo não consegue criar a fábrica.

```
...
17:07:02,316 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name queue/pedidos
17:07:02,331 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 57) HQ221003: trying to deploy queue jms.topic.noticias
17:07:02,347 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 57) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name topic/noticias
17:07:02,331 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.messaging.default.jms.connection-factory.K19Factory: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.messaging.default.jms.connection-factory.K19Factory: JBAS011639: Failed to create connection-factory
    at org.jboss.as.messaging.jms.ConnectionFactoryService$1.run(ConnectionFactoryService.java:69) [wildfly-messaging-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.1.1.Final.jar:2.1.1.Final]
Caused by: HornetQIllegalStateException[errorType=ILLEGAL_STATE message=HQ129005: Connector 'netty' not found on the main configuration file]
    at org.hornetq.jms.server.impl.JMSServerManagerImpl.internalCreateCFPOJO(JMSServerManagerImpl.java:1421) [hornetq-jms-server-2.4.5.Final.jar:]
    at org.hornetq.jms.server.impl.JMSServerManagerImpl.internalCreateCF(JMSServerManagerImpl.java:1368) [hornetq-jms-server-2.4.5.Final.jar:]
    at org.hornetq.jms.server.impl.JMSServerManagerImpl.access$1300(JMSServerManagerImpl.java:107) [hornetq-jms-server-2.4.5.Final.jar:]
    at org.hornetq.jms.server.impl.JMSServerManagerImpl$5.runException(JMSServerManagerImpl.java:1215) [hornetq-jms-server-2.4.5.Final.jar:]
    at org.hornetq.jms.server.impl.JMSServerManagerImpl.runAfterActive(JMSServerManagerImpl.java:1906) [hornetq-jms-server-2.4.5.Final.jar:]
    at org.hornetq.jms.server.impl.JMSServerManagerImpl.createConnectionFactory(JMSServerManagerImpl.java:1201) [hornetq-jms-server-2.4.5.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.messaging.jms.ConnectionFactoryService$1.run(ConnectionFactoryService.java:66) [wildfly-messaging-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    ... 4 more

17:07:02,347 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 57) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/exported/jms/topic/noticias
17:07:02,347 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) HQ221003: trying to deploy queue jms.queue.DLQ
17:07:02,347 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:/jms/queue/DLQ
17:07:02,347 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) HQ221003: trying to deploy queue jms.queue.ExpiryQueue
17:07:02,347 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue
17:07:02,347 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory
17:07:02,472 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS010406: Registered connection factory java:/JmsXA
17:07:02,488 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBWS022052: Starting JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.3.2.Final
17:07:02,545 INFO  [org.hornetq.ra] (MSC service thread 1-8) HornetQ resource adaptor started
17:07:02,545 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.services.resourceadapters.ResourceAdapterActivatorService$ResourceAdapterActivator] (MSC service thread 1-8) IJ020002: Deployed: file://RaActivatorhornetq-ra
17:07:02,545 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS010401: Bound JCA ConnectionFactory [java:/JmsXA]
17:07:02,545 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory
17:07:02,545 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "messaging"),
    ("hornetq-server" => "default"),
    ("connection-factory" => "K19Factory")
]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.messaging.default.jms.connection-factory.K19Factory" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.messaging.default.jms.connection-factory.K19Factory: JBAS011639: Failed to create connection-factory
    Caused by: HornetQIllegalStateException[errorType=ILLEGAL_STATE message=HQ129005: Connector 'netty' not found on the main configuration file]"}}
17:07:02,623 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.messaging.default.jms.connection-factory.K19Factory: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.messaging.default.jms.connection-factory.K19Factory: JBAS011639: Failed to create connection-factory
```

Alguém sabe como resolver isso?

Comment: Você configurou a *connection factor* e o *connector* (e talvez o *acceptor* também), configurou como?

Comment: Não, estas foram as únicas modificações que fiz neste arquivo...como devo configurar estas outras coisas?

Comment: Já incluo uma resposta para você.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este erro é devido ao fato de você estar referenciando um connector não existente ainda. Por padrão não existe um `netty-connector` configurado, mas outros como `http-connector`s.

Como você está usando o `standalone-full`, vou considerar que já está com o módulo/sub-sistema de mensageria habilitado (`org.jboss.as.messaging`).

Primeiro precisaremos incluir um `acceptor`, que será o reponsável por aceitar as conexões que serão feitas ao servidor do HornetQ. Para isto, no subsistema de mensageria (namespace XML `urn:jboss:domain:messaging:2.0`) localize a tag `acceptors` e inclua o seguinte trecho:

```xml
<netty-acceptor name="netty" socket-binding="messaging" />
<netty-acceptor name="netty-throughput" socket-binding="messaging-throughput">
    <param key="batch-delay" value="50"/>
    <param key="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
</netty-acceptor>
```

Depois temos que incluir um `connector`, que será o reponsável pelas configurações de transporte(como se conectar) do HornetQ. Para isto, também no subsistema de mensageria (namespace XML `urn:jboss:domain:messaging:2.0`), localize a tag `connectors` e inclua o seguinte trecho:

```xml
<netty-connector name="netty" socket-binding="messaging" />
<netty-connector name="netty-throughput" socket-binding="messaging-throughput">
    <param key="batch-delay" value="50"/>
</netty-connector>
```

Por último você deve configurar o *socket binding*. Procure pela tag `socket-binding-group` e inclua o seguinte nela:

```xml
<socket-binding name="messaging" port="5445"/>
<socket-binding name="messaging-throughput" port="5455"/>
```

Verifique as documentações do [JBoss EAP](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.4/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/chap-Messaging.html) (Obs.: existem diferenças nas configurações do EAP para o Wildfly/AS community, principalmente quanto a diretórios, mas em geral é uma boa referência e é mais detalhada) e também do [Wildfly](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Admin+Guide#AdminGuide-Messaging) pra mais detalhes da configuração e *tunning* da mensageria.

**EDIÇÃO**: incluindo explicação de como conectar e fazer *lookup* da *factory* configurada

Considerando a mesma configuração proposta na resposta e o seu `connection-factory`, o código abaixo deve funcionar:

```
final Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
props.setProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://127.0.0.1:8080");
props.setProperty(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "user");
props.setProperty(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "user1234");

final InitialContext ic = new InitialContext(props);

final ConnectionFactory factory = (ConnectionFactory) ic.lookup("jms/K19Factory");
System.out.println(factory != null ? "Factory is not null" : "Factory is null");
```

Isto por que, olhando com mais atenção, *remoting port* não mais está habilitado no Wildfly (acabei vendo que lá está, apenas nos JBoss AS, agora realmente é necessário usar o protocolo `http-remoting` que está na porta 8080.

Este é o log da execução do *lookup* (o código acima):

```
Jun 02, 2015 7:18:13 PM org.xnio.Xnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO version 3.2.0.Final
Jun 02, 2015 7:18:13 PM org.xnio.nio.NioXnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.3.1.Final
Jun 02, 2015 7:18:13 PM org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl <clinit>
INFO: JBoss Remoting version 4.0.0.Final
Factory is not null
```

E este é o log do WildFly:

```
19:18:13,731 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (default task-35) JBAS011806: Channel end notification received, closing channel Channel ID 24a74dfb (inbound) of Remoting connection 29a8f328 to /127.0.0.1:63595
```

Para executar este exemplo você precisará no seu classpath das seguintes bibliotecas:

- [`jboss-remote-naming`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss/jboss-remote-naming/2.0.4.Final)
- [`hornetq-jms-client`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hornetq/hornetq-jms-client/2.4.7.Final)
- uma que tenha um *XNIO provider*, como [`xnio-nio`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.xnio/xnio-nio/3.3.1.Final)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! Após este procedimento, no entanto, encarei o seguinte erro: "Remote connection failed: java.io.IOException: Uma conexão estabelecida foi anulada pelo software no computador host".   Alguma ideia do que seja?

Comment: @MrGuliarte já tentou usar `remote://localhost:4447` como *url provider*?

Comment: Agradeço muito sua dedicação! No entanto, trocar a porta para 4447 acarretou no seguinte erro: "Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.CommunicationException: Failed to connect to any server. Servers tried: [http-remoting://localhost:4447/ (java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information)]" , justamente quando eu tento iniciar a Connection Factory...

Comment: @MrGuliarte não é trocar só a porta, mas também o protocolo. Use `remote://localhost:4447` no lugar de `http-remoting://localhost:4447`, tentou isto?

Comment: Perdoe-me pela minha inexperiência! Fiz aqui essa troca, no entanto, o mesmo erro que acabei de comentar aparece!

Comment: @MrGuliarte veja a atualização da resposta, testei aqui e está OK, vide o log.

Comment: Funcionou! (até mesmo sem as bibliotecas, mas as adicionei mesmo assim).Muitíssimo obrigado pela sua ajuda, não conseguia achar a resposta em lugar algum!

Comment: @MrGuliarte ok, sem problemas. Vi que perguntou no SOen também, depois respondo lá pra ficar registrado por lá também. Obrigado =)